# Unity UI Toolkit - Unable to select child element

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui, ui-toolkit

I am trying to select the highlighted element using the selector shown in the search box:

`#StateEvent > * > .unity-foldout__input`

But it doesn't seem to be able to find it - no search results found. And in code it is unable to be found too with the following query:
`var stateEventLabel = debugMainRoot.Q("#StateEvent > * > .unity-foldout__input");`
[image]

What selector should I use to be able to select this element? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `var stateEventLabel = debugMainRoot.Q("StateEvent .unity-foldout__input");`

Here is a cheat sheet from UI Builder window:

[image: how to create a selector]